# VBA Excel SQL Server INSERT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I'm having trouble with an SQL Server INSERT Query.

First, here's what I am trying to achieve:

I have a list of product in an excel worksheet that I would like to export into a MS SQL Server.

Here is the code I tried:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim Client As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

//Worksheets("Config").cells(1, "B").Value contains the connection string
cn.Open Worksheets("Config").Cells(1, "B").Value

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

If Worksheets("Configuration").Cells(2, "B").Value = 1 Then
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Cardex WHERE NbCardex = ?"
ElseIf Worksheets("Configuration").Cells(2, "B").Value = 0 Then
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Cardex WHERE Name = ?"
End If

cmd.Prepared = True
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Client", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250, 
                                 UCase(Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(2, "B").Value))

Set rs = cmd.Execute

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Client = rs.Fields("NoCardex").Value
End If

rs.Close

//The code work until it reach this point, The next lines I am not sure what is wrong
//Hell I'm not even sure what i am doing.
//Problem is, nothing is added into the table
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Worksheets("Exporter").Range("Liste")
  If cell.Row > 4 And Not cell.Value = vbNullString Then
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
     cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NewTable(Dte, NbTr, NbClient, NbTr2, NbLine, NbProd, 
                         Desc, Qty, Cost, Prc, FlImp, FLDone) 
                        VALUES(?Date, ?Trans, ?Client, ?Projet, ?Ligne, ?Prod, ?Desc, 
                         ?Qte, ?Cout, ?Vend, ?Imp, 0)"
     cmd.Prepared = True

     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Date", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(1, "E").Value)
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Trans", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(1, "B").Value)
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Client", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, Client)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Projet", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(2, "E").Value)

     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Ligne", adInteger, adParamInput, , (cell.Row - 4))
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Prod", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, cell.Value)
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Desc", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8000, Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value)
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Qte", adCurrency, adParamInput, , Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value)
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Cout", adCurrency, adParamInput, , Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value)
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Vend", adCurrency, adParamInput, , Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value)
     cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Imp", adSmallInt, adParamInput, , Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value)

     cmd.Execute()
  End If
Next

cn.Close
```

I get an error that says:

```
Execution error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
The Scalar variable "@P1Date" must be declare.
```

Can anyone help me?

PS I know VBA comment aren't done with "//" but the "'" make the code less easier to read on here so I switch them out

Comment: I am a bit stumped.  You are certain that the is no reference to P1Date anywhere in your code?

Comment: Long shot but Date is often a reserved word - try using something else, or enclose it in [] wherever you use it as a parameter name.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne yes my guess is that the "?" in "?Date" get switch for "@P1" witch would be parameter number 1 and that it get squash in with the reste thus the result "@P1Date" but I dont know how to correcte this or why its doing this

Comment: @Rory I dont think this is the problem "?Date" is my parameter name inside my query it should get swith out by this line `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Date", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, Worksheets("Exporter").Cells(1, "E").Value)`

Comment: I know - couldn't hurt to at least test though using a different name. ;)

Comment: @Rory I did, it give me the error message for whatever name I give it... could it be possible that "?" isn't the prefix I am suppose to put in front of my parameters name? I've heard of "@" and tried but did not work...

Comment: @Rory let me clarify my last comment if I name the parameter "?qwerty" it still give me the error but it says "the scalar variable "@P1qwerty" must be declare."

Comment: I suspect you can't use named parameters then. Try using ? in the CommandText for each parameter and then make sure you add the parameters in the correct order. You may also want to use `@param1`, `@param2` etc in both locations so you can see what you're doing, if it's SQL Server

Comment: @Rory well it does work with only the "?", I was hoping to name the parameters because I might not be the one who will maintain this code and I wanted it to be as clear as possible. But if you dont have any other solution I would give you the answer if you would please post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think named parameters will work. Try using:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NewTable(Dte, NbTr, NbClient, NbTr2, NbLine, NbProd, 
                     Desc, Qty, Cost, Prc, FlImp, FLDone) 
                    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                     ?, ?, ?, ?, 0)"
```

and make sure that the parameters you append later are in the correct order. ;)